# C# Json Deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

I have been asked to work with json data in order to create a quiz game in windows phone. I knew that I had to use json.net to achive this which I have previously used in the past but the method I used in the past is no useful here.

My question is this. I have this json string

```
 [{"corr":"1","q":"text.","type":"0"},
    {"corr":"0","q":"text.","type":"0"},
    {"corr":"1","q":"text.","type":"0"},
    {"corr":"0","q":"text.","type":"0"},
    {"corr":"0","q":"text.","type":"0"},
    {"corr":"1","q":"text.","type":"0"},
    {"corr":"4","q":"text","a":["text","text","text","text"],"type":"1"},
    {"corr":"2","q":"text","a":["text","text","text","text"],"type":"1"},
    {"corr":"1","q":"text","a":["text","text","text","text"],"type":"1"},
    {"corr":"2","q":"text","a":["22,2%","45%","54%","67%"],"type":"1"}]
```

and as you can image I want to fill some List with the properties above.
I have created the following class in order to represent the json objects

```
public class QuizObj
{
    public string corr { get; set; }
    public string q { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<string> a { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't really know how to use it and can't find something really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var quizObjs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QuizObj>>(serializedStringValue);
string corr = quizObjs.First().corr;
// or
foreach(var quizObj in quizObjs)
{
    string corr = quizObj.corr;
    // etc
}
```

You will need to add a reference to NewtonSoft.Json, which you can get via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org) (if you haven't already).

Comment: Could you indicate how I would retrieve the values from the quizObj ;

Comment: @dotnetter It will be a strongly typed `QuizObj`. So you could, for example: `string corr = quizObj.corr;`

Comment: What Bennor said didn't work.
@Simon It's gonna be a strongly typed QuizObj but if use the code you typed which corr property I'll get ;

Comment: yeap, that worked for me too. Could someone explain to me why we used <List<QuizObj>

Comment: Because you have a collection of items. We could also have deserialized into an array or even IEnumerable<QuizObj>.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy You don't need that reference. The `JavaScriptSerializer` in the `System.Web.Script` namespace can sufficiently deserialize a list.

Comment: You do if you're using json.net (which the question was tagged with and why I used `JsonConvert`), but you're right -- there's really no need to use json.net for something this simple (providing you're using .net 3.5 or greater). Also, if you're using a client profile of .NET, you won't be able to have a reference to System.Web.